# XML validation with schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I have this xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--20160722121507-600701340-->
    <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
       <Header>
          <Action>http://tempuri.org/SalesOrder_AXService/create</Action>
       </Header>
       <Body>
          <MessageParts>
             <SalesOrder_AX>
                <SenderId>AX</SenderId>
                <SalesOrderHeaderAIF class="entity">
                   <DeliveryMode>1</DeliveryMode>
                   <ExternalSalesId>600701340</ExternalSalesId>
                   <InventLocationId>126</InventLocationId>
                   <Obs />
                   <PaymMode />
                   <SalesAmount>27.5</SalesAmount>
                   <SalesOrderDate>2016-07-22 15:12:25</SalesOrderDate>
                   <SalesOriginId>TestOrigin</SalesOriginId>
                   <SalesTaker />
                   <TaxGroup>Grp</TaxGroup>
                   <SalesOrderLinesAIF class="entity">
                      <DeliveryMode>1</DeliveryMode>
                      <ExternalSalesId>600701340</ExternalSalesId>
                      <ExternalSalesLineId>2</ExternalSalesLineId>
                      <InventLocationId>126</InventLocationId>
                      <ItemId>TestItemId</ItemId>
                      <LineAmount>27.5</LineAmount>
                      <LineDisc>27.49</LineDisc>
                      <SalesOrderedQty>1</SalesOrderedQty>
                      <SalesOriginId>TestOrigin</SalesOriginId>
                      <SalesPrice>54.99</SalesPrice>
                      <TaxItemGroup>1</TaxItemGroup>
                      <WorkerSalesResponsible />
                   </SalesOrderLinesAIF>
                   <SalesOrderCustomersAIF class="entity">
                      <City />
                      <CountryRegionId>CID</CountryRegionId>
                      <County />
                      <CustAccount>312751</CustAccount>
                      <CustGroup>CL_INT</CustGroup>
                      <CustName>Test Cust Name</CustName>
                      <DlvCity />
                      <DlvCountryRegionId>CID</DlvCountryRegionId>
                      <DlvCounty />
                      <DlvState>ST</DlvState>
                      <DlvStreet />
                      <Email>xxx@yyy.zz</Email>
                      <InvName />
                      <Phone>111111111</Phone>
                      <SalesOriginId>TestOrigin</SalesOriginId>
                      <Street />
                      <TaxGroup>Grp</TaxGroup>
                   </SalesOrderCustomersAIF>
                </SalesOrderHeaderAIF>
             </SalesOrder_AX>
          </MessageParts>
       </Body>
    </Envelope>
```

I am validating it with this schema:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message" 
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message" 
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                    elementFormDefault="qualified">

            <xsd:element name="Envelope" type="EnvelopeType"/>
            <xsd:element name="MessageParts" type="MessagePartsType"/>

            <xsd:complexType name="EnvelopeType">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Envelope of the message.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Header" type="HeaderType"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Body" type="BodyType"/>
                </xsd:sequence> 
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="HeaderType">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Header containing message metadata.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:sequence>          
                    <xsd:element name="MessageId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="SourceEndpointUser" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="SourceEndpoint" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="DestinationEndpoint" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Action" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="RequestMessageId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="BodyType">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Body of the message.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="MessageParts" type="MessagePartsType"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="MessagePartsType">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Zero or more parts of the message.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="SalesOrder_ax" type="SalesOrder_axType"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="SalesOrder_axType">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Body of the message.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="SenderId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="SalesOrderHeaderAIF" type="SalesOrderHeaderAIFType"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="SalesOrderHeaderAIFType">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Zero or more parts of the sales order header.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="DeliveryMode" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="ExternalSalesId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="InventLocationId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Obs" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="PaymMode" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="SalesAmount" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="SalesOrderDate" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="SalesOriginId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="SalesTaker" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="TaxGroup" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="SalesOrderLinesAIF" type="SalesOrderLinesAIFType"/>
                    <xsd:element name="SalesOrderCustomersAIF" type="SalesOrderCustomersAIFType"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute id="class" name="class">
                   <xsd:simpleType>
                      <xsd:restriction base="classType" />
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:attribute>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="SalesOrderLinesAIFType">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Zero or more parts of the sales order line.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="DeliveryMode" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="ExternalSalesId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="ExternalSalesLineId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="InventLocationId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="ItemId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="LineAmount" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="LineDisc" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="SalesOrderedQty" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="SalesOriginId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="SalesPrice" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="TaxItemGroup" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="WorkerSalesResponsible" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>

                <xsd:attribute name="class">
                   <xsd:simpleType>
                      <xsd:restriction base="classType" />
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:attribute>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="SalesOrderCustomersAIFType">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Zero or more parts of the customer instance.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="City" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="CountryRegionId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="County" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="CustAccount">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="CustGroup" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="CustName" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="DlvCity" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="DlvCountryRegionId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="DlvCounty" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="DlvState" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="DlvStreet" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Email" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="InvName" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Phone" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="SalesOriginId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Street" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="TaxGroup" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>

                <xsd:attribute name="class">
                   <xsd:simpleType>
                      <xsd:restriction base="classType" />
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:attribute>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:simpleType id="classType" name="classType">
               <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                  <xsd:maxLength value="70" />
               </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:schema>
```

It all works nice until i add a namespace to the SalesOrder_AX element in the xml :

```
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder_AX"
```

From this moment i get the following error:

```
 The element 'MessageParts' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message' has invalid child element 'SalesOrder_AX' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder_AX'. List of possible elements expected: 'SalesOrder_AX' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message'.
```

I really can't figure out how should i tackle this. It was there from the start but i got rid of it in order to be able to fully generate the schema.

Now the schema is generated and even i don't understand why, that namespace has to be there..

**Update with original xml file:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--20160722121507-600701340-->
    <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
       <Header>
          <Action>http://tempuri.org/SalesOrder_AXService/create</Action>
       </Header>
       <Body>
          <MessageParts>
             <SalesOrder_ATXN xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder_AX">
                <SenderId>AX</SenderId>
                <SalesOrderHeaderAIF class="entity">
                   <DeliveryMode>1</DeliveryMode>
                   <ExternalSalesId>600701340</ExternalSalesId>
                   <InventLocationId>126</InventLocationId>
                   <Obs />
                   <PaymMode />
                   <SalesAmount>27.5</SalesAmount>
                   <SalesOrderDate>2016-07-22 15:12:25</SalesOrderDate>
                   <SalesOriginId>TestOrigin</SalesOriginId>
                   <SalesTaker />
                   <TaxGroup>Grp</TaxGroup>
                   <SalesOrderLinesAIF class="entity">
                      <DeliveryMode>1</DeliveryMode>
                      <ExternalSalesId>600701340</ExternalSalesId>
                      <ExternalSalesLineId>2</ExternalSalesLineId>
                      <InventLocationId>126</InventLocationId>
                      <ItemId>TestItemId</ItemId>
                      <LineAmount>27.5</LineAmount>
                      <LineDisc>27.49</LineDisc>
                      <SalesOrderedQty>1</SalesOrderedQty>
                      <SalesOriginId>TestOrigin</SalesOriginId>
                      <SalesPrice>54.99</SalesPrice>
                      <TaxItemGroup>1</TaxItemGroup>
                      <WorkerSalesResponsible />
                   </SalesOrderLinesAIF>
                   <SalesOrderCustomersAIF class="entity">
                      <City />
                      <CountryRegionId>CID</CountryRegionId>
                      <County />
                      <CustAccount>312751</CustAccount>
                      <CustGroup>CL_INT</CustGroup>
                      <CustName>Test Cust Name</CustName>
                      <DlvCity />
                      <DlvCountryRegionId>CID</DlvCountryRegionId>
                      <DlvCounty />
                      <DlvState>ST</DlvState>
                      <DlvStreet />
                      <Email>xxx@yyy.zz</Email>
                      <InvName />
                      <Phone>111111111</Phone>
                      <SalesOriginId>TestOrigin</SalesOriginId>
                      <Street />
                      <TaxGroup>Grp</TaxGroup>
                   </SalesOrderCustomersAIF>
                </SalesOrderHeaderAIF>
             </SalesOrder_ATXN>
          </MessageParts>
       </Body>
    </Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It all works nice until i add a namespace to the SalesOrder_AX element in the xml :
>   `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder_AX"`

Adding a default namespace effectively changes the name of the element and the names of its children.  You should not be surprised to see an impact on validity.

Btw, your statement begs the question that if it really "all works nice until i add a namespace," why are you trying to add a namespace?

Anyway, your error message suggests that `SalesOrder_AX` should not be in

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder_AX
```

namespace but rather

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message
```

So, put `SalesOrder_AX` into the requested namespace rather than the one you've chosen.

---

## Update

OP has clarified that he'd like an XSD that would validate successfully against his fixed XML.

Two XSDs are needed -- one for each namespace:

### Base XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message" 
            xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder_AX" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder_AX"
              schemaLocation="SalesOrder_AX.xsd"/>

  <xsd:element name="Envelope" type="EnvelopeType"/>
  <xsd:element name="MessageParts" type="MessagePartsType"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="EnvelopeType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Envelope of the message.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Header" type="HeaderType"/>
      <xsd:element name="Body" type="BodyType"/>
    </xsd:sequence> 
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="HeaderType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Header containing message metadata.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>          
      <xsd:element name="MessageId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="SourceEndpointUser" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="SourceEndpoint" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="DestinationEndpoint" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="Action" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="RequestMessageId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="BodyType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Body of the message.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="MessageParts" type="MessagePartsType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="MessagePartsType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Zero or more parts of the message.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="s:SalesOrder_ATXN"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

**SalesOrder_AX.xsd**

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder_AX" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder_AX">


  <xsd:element name="SalesOrder_ATXN" type="s:SalesOrder_axType"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="SalesOrder_axType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Body of the message.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="SenderId" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="SalesOrderHeaderAIF" type="s:SalesOrderHeaderAIFType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="SalesOrderHeaderAIFType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Zero or more parts of the sales order header.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="DeliveryMode" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="ExternalSalesId" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="InventLocationId" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Obs" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="PaymMode" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="SalesAmount" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="SalesOrderDate" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="SalesOriginId" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="SalesTaker" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="TaxGroup" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="SalesOrderLinesAIF" type="s:SalesOrderLinesAIFType"/>
      <xsd:element name="SalesOrderCustomersAIF" type="s:SalesOrderCustomersAIFType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute id="class" name="class">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="s:classType" />
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="SalesOrderLinesAIFType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Zero or more parts of the sales order line.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="DeliveryMode" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="ExternalSalesId" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="ExternalSalesLineId" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="InventLocationId" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="ItemId" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="LineAmount" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="LineDisc" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="SalesOrderedQty" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="SalesOriginId" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="SalesPrice" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="TaxItemGroup" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="WorkerSalesResponsible" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>

    <xsd:attribute name="class">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="s:classType" />
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="SalesOrderCustomersAIFType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Zero or more parts of the customer instance.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="City" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="CountryRegionId" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="County" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="CustAccount">
        <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
          </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="CustGroup" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="CustName" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="DlvCity" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="DlvCountryRegionId" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="DlvCounty" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="DlvState" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="DlvStreet" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Email" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="InvName" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Phone" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="SalesOriginId" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Street" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="TaxGroup" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>

    <xsd:attribute name="class">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="s:classType" />
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:simpleType id="classType" name="classType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:maxLength value="70" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but i cannot change the details in the xml. I am just trying to create a schema in order to validate it.

Comment: If you cannot change the XML, why do you say in your question: *It all works nice until i **add** a namespace to the `SalesOrder_AX` element **in the xml***  ?

Comment: That's because i removed that from the start. I wanted to see if i can make it work without the namespace. And i did. But then i added back and started the investigation... with no results until now.

Comment: I've mentioned that..."It was there from the start but i got rid of it in order to be able to fully generate the schema. ". I am sorry i didn't give more details about this deletion.

Comment: So your real question is simply how to write an XSD that would find your fixed XML (exactly as it appears in your question currently) to be valid?    No other constraints?

Comment: The only thing that ruins my xsd is that namespace added on SalesOrder_AX : http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder_AX

Comment: Please add to your question the exact XML for which you wish an XSD created.  Your question is dripping in ambiguity already, and no one should spend further time on it without knowing for certain what it is you're asking.

Comment: Added the initial one.

Comment: Answer updated to provide an XSD (two, actually, are needed together) that will validate successfully against your fixed XML.

Comment: So two file for this things.. cool, it works perfectly even though some other dynamics ax details appeared on the way. Thank you very much!